# How can I vertically center multiple cells in the same line of a table?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

For example:

[image]

I've only found answers that involve centering only one column, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910478/centering-text-within-a-multirow-cell-in-latex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don't you use \centering for the horizontal centering?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

 \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}m{3em}|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  &x1&x2&x3\\\hline
  Long Label&1 &0 &1\\\hline
  Long Label&0 &1 &1\\\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah, your solution is much better than mine. Not sure why I didn't think of doing it that way....

Comment: Be careful, this solution cannot center image vertically. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty ugly and I really wouldn't recommend to make this type of table (see the discussion of how to design publication-quality tables in the documentation of [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs)), but if you're sure you want to reproduce exactly your image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{|m{3em}|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  &x1&x2&x3\\\hline
  Long Label&1 &0 &1\\\hline
  Long Label&0 &1 &1\\\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**: Your question title talks about *vertical* centering, but since you say you aren't happy with the above centering, perhaps you actually wanted *horizontal* centering also? You can get it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\begin{lrbox}{\tempbox}}%
    c<{\end{lrbox}\parbox{#1}{%
    \everypar{\vrule\@height\ht\@arstrutbox\@width\z@\everypar{}}%
    \centering\unhcopy\tempbox\@finalstrut\@arstrutbox}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{|M{3em}|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  &x1&x2&x3\\\hline
  Long Label&1 &0 &1\\\hline
  Long Label&0 &1 &1\\\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

If that is still not what you wanted, please edit your question to be more clear about what exactly you are trying to reproduce from your figure.

Comment: The text in the first column isn't centered, so this is still not exactly what I had in mind. Though I've asked elsewhere and that was also the best answer I got. I'm starting to think LaTeX just can't do it, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah that is it. I'm surprised it's possible and even more that it took all these lines of code to do it. Man, this is really discouraging, if I have to know that much just to get tables to do that. But thanks again!